# What is Filter in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, filter

I have gone through various filters in ASP.NET like, ActionFilter, AuthorizationFilterAttribute, ExceptionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter, IOperationFilter (previous two are from Swagger), and many more...
Different filters for different purpose.

But, what does "filter" mean in this context?

What entity does it filter?

Is filters always used as an attribute?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Answer (score 1):

Filters in ASP.NET Core allow code to run before or after specific stages in the request processing pipeline. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0&source=recommendations)

Authorization filters:

- Run first.
- Determine whether the user is authorized for the request.
- Short-circuit the pipeline if the request is not authorized.

Action filters:

- Run immediately before and after an action method is called.
- Can change the arguments passed into an action.
- Can change the result returned from the action.

Exception filters apply global policies to unhandled exceptions that occur before the response body has been written to. (basically centralized exception handling)

For more types and their operation flow visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#filter-types)